# Making Accordion in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am a new bee in AngularJS. I know about the angular-ui accordion. but i dont want to use that. i want to learn the basic of accordion in AngularJS by making a toy accordion by myself. here is the body part of my code.

```
 <body ng-app="MyZippy">
    <zippy slide-title="Say Hello To Universe" slide-content="Hello Universe"></zippy>
    <zippy slide-title="Say Hello To World" slide-content="Hello World"></zippy>
  </body>
```

and here is the app.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyZippy', []);

app.directive('zippy',function(){
    var linkFn = function(scope,element,attrs){
        scope.isHideContent = false;
        scope.toggleContent = function(){

           scope.isHideContent = !scope.isHideContent;

        };
    };
    return {
      restrict :"E",  
      scope:{
       zippytitle:"@slideTitle",
       zippycontent:"@slideContent"
      },
      link : linkFn,
      template : 
                  '<div ng-click="toggleContent()" style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px;width:207px"><h3 style="padding:3px;background:#ccc;width:200px;margin:0px;">{{zippytitle}}</h3>'+
                  '<div ng-show="isHideContent"><p>{{zippycontent}}</p></div></div>'
    };
});
```

How can i get the accordion effect from it? how can i get all zippy directive reference in link function? is compile function help me here? ah.. without JQuery of course
you can see output [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QiYvx7Bsy6rV0nUF5W3Q)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by accordion effect? Do I get something wrong, the accordion you posted works fine for me.

Comment: Are you talking about transition effects? Or having only one element open at the time? Even if you don't want to use accordion https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/accordion you can always have a look at its implementation as it is pure AngularJS, without jQuery. Unless you've got strong reservations about the way it was implemented, of course.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource -> i already have angular-ui as i mentioned. i want to play with it myself. one accordion-group open at a time. transition will be a bonus for me :-)